# Restrict users accessing other users' data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm having a problem of designing a common functionality of hiding information created by a user from other users. As an example,to edit Products created by USER1, normally we use one of following.

1. /Product/Edit/Id/1
2. /Product/Edit?Id=1

[image]

My concern is, if USER2 got the Id, 1, he also able to access Product with Id=1, which was created by USER1. How to restrict USER2 accessing USER1'S data? This may needs to apply for every module in the project. Is there a common way to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: There is a common way. When you read data out of the database, use a `WHERE` clause to restrict it to data owned by the current logged in user.

Comment: I am little confuse where you said "if USER2 got the Id, 1, he also able to access Product with Id=1, which was created by USER1. How to restrict USER2 accessing USER1'S data?" What does that mean?

Comment: @mjwills : how to show something like "UnAuthorize content" page with your approach?

Comment: If the query returns no data, redirect to an action called `Unauthorised`.

Comment: In general, USER1 also may have own queries which returns no data. calling Unauthorized will not be a solution.

Comment: Well then there isn't an issue. Whatever blank data you were planning to show to `USER1`, show that to the other user. Who cares? It is blank. Alternatively, pull the data down without filtering by `WHERE` clause in the database. Use LINQ to do filtering outside of the database. If the data, before and after filtering, is of a different size - redirect to `Unauthorised`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are keeping state of what user is accessing the data. You can add a `"WHERE CreatedBy = {YOURLOGGEDINUSER}"` to this query and throughout your application. Then even if he gets the ID correct no data would be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have enabled some sort of ASP.Net Authentication (The user has proved who they are) then you now need to think about the Authorization (what the user is allowed to do).

It doesn't help that these two terms are often combined or used interchangeably. In MVC a custom [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is often used to do both.

For managing records, the current logged on user is accessed via the `IPrincipal` from [`HttpContext.Current.User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.user?view=netframework-4.7.2).

The user id is usually set at `HttpContext.User.Current.Identity.Name` although you may need to do a null check if not every route is authenticated.